# Usar a mesma datalist para várias páginas

Tags: javascript, html, html5, html-option

Estou querendo fazer um sistema onde eu iria ter uma `datalist` com todos os meus `options` e em todas as páginas do meu site seria espelhado. Exemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="tCid" id="cCid" placeholder="Insira uma opção" list="cEst" />
<datalist id="cEst">
    <optgroup label="Séries Ativas">
        <option disabled>Opcao1</option>
        <option disabled>Opcao2</option>
        <option value="Opcao3">Opcao3</option>
        <option disabled>opcao4</option>
        <option disabled>Opcao5</option>
    </optgroup>
</datalist>
```

Nesse caso, vai ter um `input` para o usuário escrever uma opção e o selecionar. Só que eu quero que essa `datalist` seja única pra todas as páginas do meu site. Ou seja, quando eu tirar o `disabled` da `Opcao1` e colocar `value="Opcao1"`, ele deverá atualizar de todas as páginas do meu site que tenha essa tag `datalist`.

Comment: Porque não faz ela em um arquivo php?

Comment: Eu prefiro não fazer com php @AndersonHenrique

Comment: Angularjs então?

Comment: Pode ser qualquer JS @AndersonHenrique, mas você tem que me ajudar pois eu não sei como funciona ele.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra quem também quiser saber, fiz da seguinte forma:
Coloquei em um arquivo .txt todas as linhas de código que eu queria espelhar em todas as páginas.
Depois, eu usei o seguinte script para fazer acontecer:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("cCid").onchange=function(){ 
    //this.value tem o valor que foi escolhido nas opções
    window.location.href = "https://www.site.com/series/" + this.value + "/index.html"; 
}</script>
```

Basicamente, eu fiz o script adicionar todo o arquivo .txt no lugar do código `this.value`, fazendo o que o PHP faria muito mais fácil, porém não quis fazer com PHP. Espero ter ajudado alguém